# Node Js await not working inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, async-await

I am trying to get some data from the database with async/await then create an object with some of the data and insert into the database. I need the calls to be synchronous for this in order to send complete data for insertion.
I have an async function but the await is not working...

The code is below:

```
async function queryDb(roleName) {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    let data = await pool.request()
        .query(`select id from table where name='${roleName}'`);
    roleId = data.recordset[0].id;
    pool.close;
    sql.close;
    return roleId;
}

queryDb(roleId)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        pool.close;
        sql.close;
        console.log(err)
    })

async function program() {
    const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');
    xlsxFile('./file.xlsx').then((rows) => {
        let roleid = await queryDb(rows[0][1]); // here is not working
        let insretObj = {
            field1: rows[0][0],
            field2: rows[1][1],
            field3: rows[2][2],
            field4: rows[3][3],
            field5: rows[4][4],
            field6: rows[5][5],
            role_id: roleid,
        };
        assignRoles(insretObj);
    });

};

program().then(console.log('hereeeeeee'));
```

I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: What library are you using for your sql access?  Does it support promises?

Comment: Also, what is the point of `pool.close` and `sql.close`?  Are those supposed to be function calls that you actually call as in `pool.close()` and `sql.close()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am using mssql. 

and regarding the other one yes I suppose they are the same.

Comment: They are not the same.  A statement like `pool.close` does nothing.

Comment: @jfriend00 is this related to my problem? 

the await is not working inside program function

Comment: No, it's probably not related to this problem, but it would cause another problem later.

Comment: Where your comment says "here it is not working", what exactly does "not working" mean?  What exactly do you observe?  What exactly do you expect or want the behavior to be that is different?

Comment: @jfriend00 it shows this error "await is only valid in async function".
I except to get the roleId here and create the object below with that role id.

Comment: `.then(async (rows) => {`.. dont forget to use try/catch when using async/await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it shows this error "await is only valid in async function". I except to get the roleId here and create the object below with that role id.

Your use of `await` is inside the nested `.then()` handler callback which is not itself `async`.

In general, you don't want to mix `.then()` and `await` within the same control-flow.  I would suggest you change it to this:

```
const xlsxFile = require('read-excel-file/node');

async function program() {
    let rows = await xlsxFile('./file.xlsx');
    let roleid = await queryDb(rows[0][1]);
    let insretObj = {
        field1: rows[0][0],
        field2: rows[1][1],
        field3: rows[2][2],
        field4: rows[3][3],
        field5: rows[4][4],
        field6: rows[5][5],
        role_id: roleid,
    };

    assignRoles(insretObj);
}
```